# No puedo ingresar a mi carpeta con el comando cd en GIT

Tags: git

Hola alguien me puede ayudar, en un momento funcionó pero de repente paso este problema. Dice que no encuentra el directorio. La ruta esta perfectamente escrita.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin estar en Güindo$, te diría que el problema es el *slash* (`\\``). Prueba a usar la otra barra (la del 7, `/`), o bien a poner la ruta completa entre comillas dobles (`"`).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.